# Tomcat6 getting crashed at regular intervals installed in Ubuntu

Tags: tomcat6

I have installed Tomcat6 in Ubuntu OS and when I run my web application the server gets crashed at regular intervals. I have tried a lot but not getting the solution. I have increased the memory upto 2048mb but still getting such error. Following is the error I am getting. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters processParametersINFO: 
Invalid chunk starting at byte [312] and ending at byte [312] with a value of    [null] 
ignoredException in thread "Timer-1" Exception in thread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" Exception in thread
"com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" Exception in thread    
"com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" Exception in thread 
"Timer-2" Exception in thread "http-8080-4" Exception in thread "http-8080-8" Exception in    thread 
"http-8080-17" Exception in thread "org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.data"   Exception in thread 
"org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache.data" Exception in thread 
"org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.data" Exception in thread   
"org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.data" Exception in thread 
"org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache.data" Exception in thread 
"org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.data" Exception in thread 
"org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.data" Exception in thread 
"org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache.data" Exception in thread "com.safenet.usermgmt.User.data" 
Exception in thread "http-8080-7" Exception in thread  "http-8080-12" Exception in thread "http-8080-16" 
Exception in thread "http-8080-14"   Exception in thread "http-8080-13" Exception in thread "http-8080-15" 
Exception in thread   "http-8080-6" 
OpenJDK Client VM warning: Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError occurred   dispatching signal SIGTERM to handler- the VM may need to be forcibly terminated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the server, archive the log files. Restart the server. When the exception occurs, post the full stacktrace.  If the error doesn't occur for a long time, you may need to add:

-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow

to your CATALINA_OPTS.

Check your application is correctly closing any DB connections it uses in the finally block of the try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you start your Tomcat-instance with the jmxremote enabled it will be easier for you to determine any problem.

Add the following to the `CATALINA_OPTS` environment variable for Tomcat and restart the JVM.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

After this is done, you can use `jconsole` to monitor the memory usage and look for unusual trends. You might have a serious memory leak in your application that causes this.